# Where does package make-doc end up after installation?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, linux-mint

I am on Mint 12 KDE. I used Software Manager to install make-doc - "Documentation for the gnu version of the "make" utility".

How do I access what was downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All documentation packages (*-doc) in ubuntu are installed in `/usr/share/doc`. You can browse to it and read the documentation at `/usr/share/doc/make-doc/`.

If you have apache installed, it automatically creates an alias for `/doc` to `/usr/share/doc` in the `default` host, meaning you can browse to `http://localhost/doc/make-doc` for the documentation.

On a broader note, after installing any package, you can view where its files went by `dpkg -L package-name`

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, you can list the files in an installed package:

```
dpkg -L make-doc
```

I don't know Mint's Software Center, but I think that if you go to the installed packages section and select `make-doc`, there is a menu item to display a list of files in the package.

You can list the files in a package that isn't installed, by the way — this is especially useful in the other direction, to find the package containing a file whose name you know. Install `apt-file` and run `apt-file list packagename` or `apt-file search filename`. Linux Mint only added support for `apt-file` [recently](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/898425), so I'm not sure whether it works before Maya.

Comment: Thaks Gilles, I have apt-file installed now.